# Pandas cell value is a column name in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two huge dataframes.
For the sake of simplicity,

```
df1:
Item   Date   Demand   
A       01     Jan
A       02     Jan
A       03     Jan
B       01     Apr
B       02     Apr
B       03     Apr
C       01     Mar
C       02     Mar
C       03     Mar


df2:
Item   Date   Jan   Feb    Mar   Apr   May    Jun
 A     01     343   335    343   231   234    345
 A     02     340   331    344   230   230    343
 A     03     373   334    341   235   264    344
 B     01     345   456    455   453   612    342
 B     02     348   450    453   455   642    345
 B     03     346   459    452   454   632    342
 C     01     456   341    832   342   123    411
 C     02     452   340    836   341   423    413
 C     03     451   348    837   346   153    410
```

For `df1`, I want to replace the Month name present in `demand` column with its value from `df2`.
For example, In the first row, `Jan` should be replaced by `343` which is the value in `Jan` column of `df2` for `Item A, Date 01`

The final output should look like this -

```
    Item   Date   Demand   
    A       01     343
    A       02     340
    A       03     373
    B       01     453
    B       02     455
    B       03     454
    C       01     832
    C       02     836
    C       03     837
```

I tried different ways, but none of them worked. Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

thushv89's answer is good! However, in a different situation you may want to just `melt` df2.

```
df2 = df2.melt(id_vars=['Item','Date'],
               value_vars=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun'],
               var_name='Month',
               value_name='Demand')
```

Output:

```
   Item  Date Month  Demand
0     A     1   Jan     343
1     A     2   Jan     340
2     A     3   Jan     373
3     B     1   Jan     345
4     B     2   Jan     348
5     B     3   Jan     346
6     C     1   Jan     456
7     C     2   Jan     452
8     C     3   Jan     451
9     A     1   Feb     335
10    A     2   Feb     331
11    A     3   Feb     334
12    B     1   Feb     456
13    B     2   Feb     450
14    B     3   Feb     459
...
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df2 = df2.set_index(['Item', 'Date'], drop=True)
df["Demand"] = df.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[(x.Item,x.Date), x.Demand], axis=1)
```